# Django Template: looping through two lists

Tags: django

I have two lists of Django model objects, which I want to display on a template. `list1` is a one-dimensional array, and `list1` is a two-dimensional array. In the template, I want to loop through each element in `list1`, display its value, and then display all the values of the corresponding element in `list2`.

For example, if `list1 = ['Andrew', 'Ben,' 'Charles']` and `list2 = [[3, 4, 8], [12, 9], [10, 0, 5, 1]]`, then I want to display:

```
- Andrew
    - 3
    - 4
    - 8
- Ben
    - 12
    - 9
- Charles
    - 10
    - 0
    - 5
    - 1
```

My question is, in my template, how can I loop through `list1` and then access the corresponding element of `list2`? The following code is what I have so far:

```
<ul>
    {% for name in list1 %}
    <li>{{ name }}
        <ul>
            {% for A %}
            <li>{{ B }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>    
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What should I write in place of `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the python view you can zip them together.

### view.py

```
def someview(request):
    list1 = ['Andrew', 'Ben,' 'Charles']
    list2 = [[3, 4, 8], [12, 9], [10, 0, 5, 1]]
    zipped_list = zip(list1, list2)
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', {'zipped_list': zipped_list})
```

### base/home.html

```
<ul>
    {% for item1 in zipped_list %} <- this is now a tuple with the first element being our first item and the second element being a list
    <li>{{ item1.0 }}
        <ul>
            {% for secondItem in item1.1 %}
                <li>{{ secondItem }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>    
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should zip them together in your view.

```
combined_list = zip(list1, list2)
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
{% for item in combined_list %}
    {{ item.0 }}
    {% for value in item.1 %}
         {{ item.1 }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: [`{% for list1_item, list2_item in combined_list %}` would be much clearer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for)