# Django forloop.counter0 to read a list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

read a list in a list in the template with example:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

how to access to **new_list** value in the template

```
{% for value in a_list %}
    <h2>{{ a_new_list.forloop.counter.0 }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

i do this and It's not work!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358805/django-template-looping-through-two-lists

Comment: `{{ a_new_list.forloop.counter0 }}` instead `{{ a_new_list.forloop.counter.0 }}`

Answer (score 0):

Why not iterate only new_list?

```
{% for value in new_list %}
    <h2>{{ value }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I forget, I need value in List **a_list** too! So I can't iterate only new_list