# Django how do you loop using range through two lists simultaneiously

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django and would like to iterate through two lists so that the're side by side:
my views file:

```
def displayDict(request):
     data = ["a", "b", "c"]
     data2 = ["x", "y", "z"]
     return render(request, 'chattr.html',
     {'range': range(0,len(data)-1),'dictItems': data, "otherDict" : "other_bot", "dictItems_bot": data2, "otherDict2": "bot" , "duo" : (data, data2)})
```

my template:

```
{% for i in range %}
    <p>
        {{i}} <br>
        <b>{{otherDict}}:</b> {{dictItems.i}} <br>
        <b>{{otherDict2}}:</b> {{dictItems_bot.i}} <br>
        {% comment %} {{a|add:1}} {% endcomment %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like a webpage that looks like:  
**other_bot:** 'a' 
**dictItems_bot:** 'x'  
**other_bot:** 'b'  
**dictItems_bot:** 'y'  
**other_bot:** 'c'  
**dictItems_bot:** 'z'

Currently nothing renders except the bot names:  
**other_bot:**   
**dictItems_bot:**   
**other_bot:**   
**dictItems_bot:**

I may also be able to do this inner loop using tuples,  [Django Template: looping through two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358805/django-template-looping-through-two-lists). But this would be a lot more complex,...

Answer (score 1):

try this...

view.py

```
def display_dict(request):
    data = ["a", "b", "c"]
    data2 = ["x", "y", "z"]
    context = {"data": zip(data, data2), "otherDict": "other_bot","otherDict2": "dictItems_bot"}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

HTML

```
{% for element in data %}
    <p><b>{{ otherDict }}:</b>{{ element.0 }}</p>
    <p><b>{{ otherDict2 }}:</b>{{ element.1 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks @Nikunj I'm hoping to be able to iterate through an array that mihgt have hundreds of entries

Comment: No problem with hundreds of elements. `zip` returns an iterator object. When you use it in a forloop context it generates one pair for each iteration. Its memory (and other) overhead is small. It doesn't generate a new list of pairs unless you force matters, f.ex. `list(zip(data1, data2))`

Answer (score 0):

For these sorts of issues I have Django Debug Toolbar installed, which lets me see the context. I suspect your 'range' has an issue because {{i}} is not being rendered (or is it?), so you are just looping once instead of thrice, i.e. not looping at all.